# Which version/service pack of Adobe CQ5 is running?

Tags: adobe, aem, sling

Given a running author or publish instance of Adobe CQ5, how can one tell which major version and service pack of the software is in use?  Is there a place to look for a simple "v5.5 SP2" answer?

I don't work with our CQ5 stuff often, and I'm bringing up an Amazon EC2 instance running CQ5 and I need to know which revision of the software it is running, and find out which version the source of the backup that I would like to restore is running.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you sign in, you can see the version on the Welcome page. It's at the bottom of the page
[image: where to find out the version]

Comment: Wow. How did I miss that?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank for your appreciation! Maybe because the text is too small :)

Answer (score 1):

From the command line you can access it like this

```
curl -H "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n admin:admin|base64)" http://localhost:4503/system/console/status-productinfo.txt
```

This is text response you can grep / sed for the parts of the version you need.